# How to scroll a long page consisting a mix of tableviews and other view elements

Tags: ios, ruby, automation, cucumber, calabash

I have a long page consisting a mix of table views and other view elements (e.g. textviews, images, buttons, etc).

Since iOS reuses table cells when scrolling, I've been getting an infinite loop when I scroll down the page because the element I use to stop the loop doesn't 'exist' (it's actually there, but gets messed up because of the tableview).

I use this command to scroll down the page in general:

```
scroll "scrollView", :down
```

However, this command doesn't work that well against table views (I usually use `each_cell` command when the page 100% consists of tableviews)

I wonder if there is a command to scroll a page regardless UI types in iOS.

Comment: please post either your code or the screen shots with details how you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to fix the issue :)

```
scroll("scrollView index:0", :down)
```